# How to break down create a substring method

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me break down this problem? I have the answer but I'm not really sure how my teacher got to it.

```
class String
# Write a method, String#substrings, that takes in a optional length argument
# The method should return an array of the substrings that have the given length.
# If no length is given, return all substrings.
#
# Examples:
#
# "cats".substrings     # => ["c", "ca", "cat", "cats", "a", "at", "ats", "t", "ts", "s"]
# "cats".substrings(2)  # => ["ca", "at", "ts"]
 def substrings(length = nil)
    subs = []
    (0...self.length).each do |start_idx|
        (start_idx...self.length) do |end_idx|
            sub = self[start_idx..end_idx]
            subs << sub                
        end
    end

    if length.nil?
      subs
    else
      subs.select { |str| str.length == length}
    end
 end 
end
```

The start_idx and the end_idx are really confusing, if the start_idx is "ca" for example is the end_idx "ca" as well? Please help..

Comment: `start_idx` is an index, a number, not a string. Same for `end_idx`.

Comment: Im not really getting how it starts at "c" then "ca" then "cat" the "cats" then to "a"

Answer (score 2):

So think of `start_idx` and `end_idx` as a constantly changing variable.

```
def substrings(length = nil)
    subs = []
    # in the case of 'cats' the length is 4
    # so this is making an array UP TO BUT NOT INCLUDING 4
    # [0,1,2,3].each do ...
    # let's take 0
    (0...self.length).each do |start_idx|
        # start_idx = 0 the first time through this each
        # Array from start_idx UP TO BUT NOT INCLUDING 4
        # so the FIRST time through this is 0, second time through is 1, ...
        #[0,1,2,3].each do ...
        (start_idx...self.length) do |end_idx|
            # end_idx = 0
            # slice of the string from the 0th to the 0th value (first letter)
            sub = self[start_idx..end_idx]
            subs << sub                
        end
    end

    if length.nil?
      subs
    else
      subs.select { |str| str.length == length}
    end
 end
```

So think of this as a bunch of nested loops using numbers that are reassigned during each pass of the loop.

Does that help?

Comment: kinda, what really confuses me is the second iteration (1). how does it get "ca" from "c" and so on

Answer (score 1):

The following would be a more Ruby-like way of writing that.

```
class String
  def all_substrings
    (1..size).flat_map { |n| all_substrings_by_length(n) }
  end

  def all_substrings_by_length(length)
    each_char.each_cons(length).with_object([]) { |a,arr| arr << a.join }
  end
end
```

---

```
"cats".all_substrings_by_length(1)
  #=> ["c", "a", "t", "s"] 
"cats".all_substrings_by_length(2)
  #=> ["ca", "at", "ts"] 
"cats".all_substrings_by_length(3)
  #=> ["cat", "ats"] 

"cats".all_substrings
  #=> ["c", "a", "t", "s", "ca", "at", "ts", "cat", "ats", "cats"]
```

---

Note that `1..size` is the same as `1..self.size`, `all_substrings_by_length(n)` is the same as `self.all_substrings_by_length(n)` and `each_char` is the same as `self.each_char`, as `self` is implied when a method has no explicit receiver.

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char), [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Emumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).

---

Let's break down

```
each_char.each_cons(length).with_object([]) { |a,arr| arr << a.join }
```

when `length = 2` and `self = "cats"`.

```
length = 2
e0 = "cats".each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "cats":each_char>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e0.to_a
  #=> ["c", "a", "t", "s"]
```

Continuing,

```
e1 = e0.each_cons(length)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "cats":each_char>:each_cons(2)> 
e1.to_a
  #=> [["c", "a"], ["a", "t"], ["t", "s"]] 

e2 = e1.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #     "cats":each_char>:each_cons(2)>:with_object([])> 
e2.to_a    
  #=> [[["c", "a"], []], [["a", "t"], []], [["t", "s"], []]]
```

By examining the return values for the creation of `e1` and `e2` one can see that they could be thought of as *compound enumerators*, though Ruby has no formal concept of such. Also, as will be seen, the empty arrays in the last return value will be built up as the calculations progress.

Lastly,

```
e2.each { |a,arr| arr << a.join }
  #=> ["ca", "at", "ts"]
```

which is our desired result. Now examine this last calculation in more detail. `each` directs `e2` to generate an element and then sets the block variables equal to it.

First, observe the following.

```
e2
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "cats":each_char>:
  #     each_cons(2)>:=with_object(["ca", "at", "ts"])>
```

This shows us that we need to return `e2` to its initial state in order to reproduce the calculations.

```
e2 = e1.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #     "cats":each_char>:each_cons(2)>:with_object([])>
```

Then:

```
a, arr = e2.next
  #=> [["c", "a"], []]
```

[Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) breaks this array into parts for `a` and `arr`:

```
a #=> ["c", "a"] 
arr
  #=> []
```

We now perform the block calculation:

```
arr << a.join
  #=> ["ca"]
```

`each` then commands `e2` to generate the next element, assigns values to the block variables and performs the block calculation.

```
a, arr = e2.next
  #=> [["a", "t"], ["ca"]]
a #=> ["a", "t"]
arr
  #=> ["ca"]
arr << a.join
  #=> ["ca", "at"]
```

This is repeated once more.

```
a, arr = e2.next
  #=> [["t", "s"], ["ca", "at"]] 
arr << a.join
  #=> ["ca", "at", "ts"]
```

Lastly, the exception

```
a, arr = e2.next
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

causes `each` to return

```
arr
  #=> ["ca", "at", "ts"]
```

from the block, which, being the last calculation, is returned by the method.